# VBA_Multiple Public or Global Variables In A Simple Way

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a project where I would like to use Global variables which will be used in different modules. Now I've code which is very lengthy since multiple variables i.e. more than 10 needs to be used. Each time I had to use "Function FiltCol As Variant" & "Function LastRow As Long". Is there a way to simply it & include all the variables in a single "Function"?

```
Option Explicit
Function FiltCol() As Variant
    FiltCol = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Emp ID", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
End Function
Function LastRow() As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, FiltCol).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Function FiltCol1() As Variant
    FiltCol1 = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Emp Name", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
End Function
Function LastRow1() As Long
    LastRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, FiltCol1).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Function FiltCol2() As Variant
    FiltCol2 = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Designation", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
End Function
Function LastRow2() As Long
    LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, FiltCol2).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Function FiltCol3() As Variant
    FiltCol3 = Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Country", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
End Function
Function LastRow3() As Long
    LastRow3 = Cells(Rows.Count, FiltCol3).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

So on.... I would like to use more than 10 variables. Please advise if all these variables can be accommodated in single "Function" so that it will be used in different modules.

Comment: There are no Global variables in your code. FIltCol, FIltCol1, FIltCol2 are all functions.

Comment: Yes, all these are functions. I'm looking if these can be set as Global Variables so that it can be used in different modules.

Comment: No `Global` variables involved and it should be possible to create such 'unique' function, but I think it is useless. You cannot use them 'in different modules' if they do not refer the same ranges. And even they refer the same ranges, it is simpler to determine the last row (for instance) in the usual simple way: `lastRow = Range("A" & rows.count).end(xlUp).row` and use it in all modules. Of course, if all modules need to process the same column. But this is not so probable, I would dare to suppose...

Comment: @Satish If you declare the functions as Public, you can call them in different modules.

Answer (score 0):

"*Global variables*" and "*code which is very lengthy*" are phrases together that a code maintainer dreads !. You probably should be using class modules and adopting an object orientated approach but if you simply want to return multiple variables from a function you can use an array.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
   Dim rng As Range, s As String, ar
   s = "Emp ID"
   Set rng = Rows("1:1")
   ar = FiltCol(rng, s)
   MsgBox s & " Col=" & ar(0) & " Rows=" & ar(1)
End Sub

Function FiltCol(rng As Range, s As String) As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet, found As Range
    Dim iCol As Integer, iLastRow As Long
    
    Set ws = rng.Parent
    Set found = rng.Find(What:=s, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If found Is Nothing Then
        FiltCol = Array(0, 0)
    Else
        iCol = found.Column
        iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
        FiltCol = Array(iCol, iLastRow)
    End If
    
End Function
```